# std::unique_ptr custom deleter that takes two arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I am working on legacy code where memory allocation/deallocation done in traditional C style, but want to wrap it in a unique_ptr with a custom deleter. Consider a case where a 2 dimensional array is allocated by legacy code by calling calloc/malloc. I need to call the corresponding legacy deallocator function taking two parameters - pointer to array and size of the array. How to define a custom deleter that takes 2 parameters in this case, both will be passed only at the time of initializing the unique_ptr to take ownership of already allocated array? Thanks in advance.

A simplified(yet contrived) example below:

```
    // function allocates memory and returns size of the buffer
    void legacyFunction(char **array, int *num)
    {
        char *p = (char *)calloc(5, sizeof(char));
        for (auto i=0; i<5; ++i)
        {
            p[i] = 'a';
        }
        *num = 5;
        *array = p;
        return;
    }

int main()
{
    char *array = nullptr;
    int numofElts = 0;
    legacyFunction(&array, &numofElts);
    // unique_ptr here to take ownership of array
    // custom deleter should take both pointer and size
    // the size could be any number based on business use case

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Legacy code fetches records from a database table, allocates the buffer to hold them and returns both buffer pointer and buffer size

Comment: Could you maybe provide a better example, preferably one that doesn't invoke *undefined behavior* as the current code does? What type exactly will be stored inside the `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: You could use a lambda as your custom deleter and have it capture all the information you need.

Comment: @UnholySheep modified the example to make it clearer

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong path, but is there any specific reason to use a `std::unique_ptr` here instead of a custom wrapper class? In cases like these I personally feel that the encapsulation a custom class gives tends to look cleaner

Comment: Show how the legacy code would release the memory. Normally, it would just be a call to `free`; but why would it need the size of the array, `free` need not be told how much it has to free?

Comment: @UnholySheep - it's part of an exercise to modernize legacy C code to modern C++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deleter is an object. It can hold onto the size.

```
struct LegacyDeleter
{
  int size;
  void operator()(char** ptr) const noexcept
  { legacyDeallocate(ptr, size); }
};
using legacy_ptr = std::unique_ptr<char*, LegacyDeleter>;

int main()
{
   legacy_ptr ptr(legacyAllocatorFunction(5), LegacyDeleter{5});
}
```

Comment: or perhaps `legacy_ptr allocate_legacy(int size) { return legacy_ptr(legacyAllocatorFunction(size), LegacyDeleter{size}); }`